# KineticsJS - Collision detection not working on newly added shape

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, kineticjs

I have a group of shapes added to the stage when initializing my scene. I am then using

```
Shape.intersects(point)
```

to check for collision between initial shapes and other shapes thrown as projectiles. It works fine.

But if I add a new shape to the group, the intersects() method doesn't detect collision between a projectile and the newly added shape. The new shape is seen as a children of my group of shapes though.

I have also tried using

```
Kinetic.Stage#getIntersection
```

but it also fail detecting the collision with new shape.

Any help in solving this problem would be appreciated !

**EDIT**
Here is a JSFiddle reproducing the problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/matdev/3dYHA/

Can anyone explain to me why is the projectile not colliding with the first circle ?

Here is my collision detection function:

```
    function checkCollision(meteore) {
        var hasCollided = false;
        var children = wholePlanet.getChildren();

        for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {  // for each single shape
                var r = children[i];
                if (r != planet) {
                    hasCollided = r.intersects(meteore.getX(), meteore.getY());

                    if (hasCollided) {
                        alert("Collision detected !")
                        if (r.shapeType == meteore.shapeType) {
                            var fillColor = meteore.getFill();
                            r.setFill(fillColor);
                            meteore.remove();
                        } else {
                            meteore.remove();
                        }

                        break;
                    }
                }
        }

        return hasCollided;
    }
```

Comment: please add relevant (more) code to understand your structure. Best option would be a working fiddle to test

Comment: HI Ani, I did include a link towards a working fiddle. Any idea on how to fix the problem ?